# Python, how to substitute one level of a path for "anything" or "*"

Tags: python

I am making a search script for parsing log files in archives and am stuck at one particular thing I didnt find resources anywhere else.

I need to somehow replace the "id1" of this string for "anything". Simply put I want the script to take anything in that particular place in path. Is this possible only by using logZip as one huge regex?

```
logZip = ("c:/logs/" + str(id1) + "/" + str(id2) + "/" + str(id1) + "_log_" + str(dateID) + "_" + str(hourID) + "-00_" + str(id2) + ".zip")
```

As requested, Im adding a sample paths and files I want to define:

```
c:/logs/aaa1/sss2/aaa1_log_2013-01-14-13-00_sss2.zip
c:/logs/aaa2/sss2/aaa2_log_2013-01-14-13-00_sss2.zip
c:/logs/aaa3/sss2/aaa3_log_2013-01-14-13-00_sss2.zip
```

Next step will be to make the same thing with sss2 part.

Comment: Question seems very unclear.. Can you paste a sample path or something to the question.

Comment: Does `listdir` from `os` package work? I mean you can list all the sub-directories in `logs` and construct your path manually by iterating the sub-directory names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import glob
import os

id1 = '*'
logZip = glob.glob(os.path.join("c:/logs", id1, id2, '{}_log_{}_{}-00_{}.zip'.format(id1, dateID, hourID, id2)))
```

returns a list of complete paths to files where `id1` is replaced by a wildcard `*`.

`os.path.join` makes the path construction clearer.

If `logZip` has to be a single file, you can use `glob.iglob`, which returns an iterator:

```
id1 = '*'
mask = os.path.join("c:/logs", id1, id2, '{}_log_{}_{}-00_{}.zip'.format(id1, dateID, hourID, id2))
for logZip in glob.iglob(mask):
    # logZip is a single file
```

Comment: This is actually superb, thank you very much :) Now I only have to somehow tell zipFile module to iterate over the list produced by your code. Because by default, zipFile cannot open files from a list, but only one defined file as far as I know. Anyhow, thats another matter I will try to deal with later on. Thanks again.

Comment: @eumiro Thanks a bunch, I allready iterated over the list returned from the original glob, but will implement this as its easier to read ;) Thanks a lot again.